# How to check an input using asynchronous data

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm using angularfire2 to implement firebase to my ionic app. where I need to check or uncheck an input based on the realtime database. here is my implementation.

`<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" [checked]={{(booked | async)?.booked}} >`

this is giving me HTML error.

Answer (score 1):

Because `[checked]` is expecting a variable you don't need to wrap in brackets.

You should be able to do the following;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" [checked]="(booked | async)?.booked">
```

OR

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" checked="{{ (booked | async)?.booked }}">
```

Have a read on up on the template syntax in the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-). It explains property binding in more detail.